# Search a base class's object in a Set of Derived class

Tags: java, hashset

I've a class called `Skill` as:

```
public class Skill {
    private final int type;
    private final int level;

    public Skill(int type, int level) {
        this.type = type;
        this.level = level;
    }

    // Getters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = 17;
        h = 31 * h + type;
        h = 31 * h + level;
        return h;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj instanceof Skill) {
            Skill that = (Skill) obj;
            return this.type == that.type && this.level == that.level;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Another called `PSkill` as:

```
public class PSkill extends Skill {
    private final int preferenceLevel;
    private final boolean mandatory;

    public PSkill(int type, int level, int preferenceLevel, boolean mandatory) {
        super(type, level);
        this.preferenceLevel = preferenceLevel;
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    // Getters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj instanceof PSkill) {
            PSkill that = (PSkill) obj;
            return super.equals(obj) 
                && this.preferenceLevel == that.preferenceLevel
                && this.mandatory == that.mandatory;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My requirement:**
Search a set of `PSkill` objects to find a match for `Skill` object.
For e.g.: `Skill - type:1, level:2` is a match for `PSkill - type:1, level:2, preferenceLevel: any, mandatory: any`

When I run the below, it works.

```
public class Invoker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<PSkill> skills = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new PSkill(1, 1, 1, true), new PSkill(1, 2, 1, true)));
        System.out.println(skills.contains(new Skill(1, 1))); // prints true
        System.out.println(skills.contains(new Skill(1, 3))); // prints false
    }
}
```

And I know why because the `hashCode()` implementation for both types is same and in `HashSet` implementation, `key.equals(k)` is used and key in my case is `Skill` object and hence, the equality works.

*From HashSet implementation*

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))  // here
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) // and here
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know I broke the `hashCode()` and `equals()` contract. But the code is working as it should, i.e. check if a `Skill` matches any of the `PSkill`s in the set.

**My question is:**
Is the equality check `key.equals(k)` in `HashSet` implementation dependent and could be reversed in a future release i.e. `k.equals(key)` and the code will stop working?
Also, any better ways to do it which could make it less fragile without simply looping over the collection? Thanks

Comment: will it still work if you change the order of insertions?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker changing order of insertions of `PSkill` objects into the set? Well yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is certainly not guaranteed. The contract is that if you provide correct implementations of hashCode and equals, you get a correct implementation of a hashset. If you don't follow your end of the contract, you don't have any guarantees on how well a set will work.